# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError + ant - running a jar

Tags: java, selenium, ant

Tagging- Selenium as well just in case someone faced similar issue while creating selenium tests using Ant.

I have seen lot of questions/answers on this topic, tried all the options suggested on various forums but still my issue is not getting resolved. Basically i compile code(includes the test scripts), create JAR and run the same JAR. For some reason it does not seem to identify the libraries during run time. Same code(With tests) works fine when main() method is run from Eclipse. Here is the build.xml,

```
<project default="run">

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build" />
</target>

<target name="init-classpath">
    <path id="lib.classpath">
        <fileset dir="./lib/">
            <include name="**.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" ">
        <path refid="lib.classpath" />
        <flattenmapper />
    </pathconvert>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="clean, init-classpath">
    <javac classpathref="lib.classpath" destdir="./compiled" failonerror="true" srcdir="./src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
    <jar destfile="build/jar/BANC.jar" basedir="compiled">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.portico.driver.TestDriver" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="build/jar/BANC.jar" fork="true">
    </java>
</target>

</project>
```

Error:-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/Workbook

Manifest content

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_41-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.portico.driver.TestDriver
Class-Path: activation.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar jna-3.4.0.jar jxl.jar 
 logging-selenium-1.2.jar mail.jar ojdbc14.jar poi-3.0.2-FINAL.jar rep
 ortng-1.1.1.jar saxon-8.7.jar selenium-grid-demo-1.0.7.jar selenium-g
 rid-demo-standalone-1.0.7.jar selenium-grid-hub-1.0.7.jar selenium-gr
 id-hub-standalone-1.0.7.jar selenium-grid-remote-control-1.0.7.jar se
 lenium-grid-remote-control-standalone-1.0.7.jar selenium-grid-tools-1
 .0.7.jar selenium-grid-tools-standalone-1.0.7.jar selenium-server-1.0
 .3-standalone.jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar sikuli-script
 .jar testng-6.8.jar velocity-1.7.jar
```

Comment: Did u include  Include jxl.jar???

Comment: In the lib folder , does the jxl.jar exists ?

Comment: Yes all the required JARs are present in the lib folder.

Comment: does the jar gets created ?

Comment: Can u please unjar it and see whether the same jar exists ?

Comment: It is building the JAR successfully. Manifest file contents are(did not put entire content, but lists all the JARs as space seperated),  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_41-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.portico.driver.TestDriver
Class-Path: activation.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar jna-3.4.0.jar jxl.jar

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is, whether the problem is connected with the manifest or something else. If you can run your application with `java -cp <allthejarfiles> <main-class>` the problem is connected with the manifest. Keep in mind that the jar files specified in the manifest are relative to the jar file’s location. Trying to run the application with the -verbose:class option gives hint about which jar are really loaded.

Comment: I have put the Manifest file contents in above comment. About jar file location - It seems to be reading from the correct library folder, because when i tried to change, it throwed an error about folder does not exists. My project structure is projectroot/src(source code), projectroot/compiled(compiled code), projectroot/lib(contains all project libraries), projectroot/build/jar(JAR directory)....do you think any changes are required in manifest classpath?

Comment: In your comment I don’t see any paths so the JVM would expect all jars to be within the same directory. This doesn’t match the description of having a directory for the built jar and another for the referenced libs (unless these libs are copied to the build target directory as well). Did you ever try running your app with specifying all jars manually?

Comment: Manifest file contents are(did not put entire content, but lists all the JARs as space seperated), Manifest-Version: 1.0 Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3 Created-By: 1.6.0_41-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) Main-Class: com.portico.driver.TestDriver Class-Path: activation.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar jna-3.4.0.jar jxl.jar

Comment: I know. They are space separated but simple file names without any path prefix. So they have to be in the same directory as the application jar. Are they?

Comment: I copied the libraries to the jar directory but still it failed. How can i pass full path to manifest classpath?

Comment: *Please* try to run it with a manually specified class path like `java -verbose:class -cp <allthejarfiles> <main-class>` to see whether it really is a manifest issue. And if it works this way, try `java -verbose:class -jar <appjar>` to see where the logs differ.

Comment: It works if mainclass is executed but not for jar. the logs for jar do not show the libraries being loaded

Comment: Then it’s the manifest and maybe we need more details. Can you post the entire manifest without simplifications? (Add it to your original question seems to be the best way)

Comment: Tried mf.classpath with space and semicolon seperator but still same error

Comment: Please check whether there is a newline character at the end of the classpath line. There *must* be a newline character if it is the last line of the manifest.

Comment: The last chance is to use OS-level tools like procmon (Windows) or strace (others) to monitor whether the JVM ever attempts to read the jar files. This might give a hint about wrong paths or other failures or, in case it doesn’t even try, the inability to parse the manifest correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest assumes the jars in the current working directory.  So it would require dir attribute set to the folder where  the jar exists.

[Java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)  supports providing classpath in the arguments.  Try giving the classpath in arguments.

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="build/jar/BANC.jar" fork="true"  dir="build/jar" >
        <classpath>
           <pathelement path="${lib.classpath}"/>
         </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in my project. I suggest that you should create a separate  directory specially for the jar files, put all of your jars in that directory, and then point the lib address to that directory.

for example in your case say I have created a directory `D:/jar_collection`, where I have put all my jars physically.

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="D:/jar_collection"/>
<target name="setClassPath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath" refid="classpath_jars" />
</target>
```

and it works fine. Please try it once.